# Pass data to UITableViewCell when initialising

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable that I need to pass from the main UITableView to the cell subview to use in the initialisation method. I tried doing this:

```
class CollectionCell : UITableViewCell {

    var collectionElement  : PFObject = PFObject(className:"CollectionElement")

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.collectionElementArray = (collectionElement["elementFileArray"] as? [PFObject])!

...

}
```

I then create the cell in this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

...
    let cell : CollectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

    cell.collectionElement = collectionElements[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

The variable is not set in the init method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ncerezo says the cells are not getting created, they are getting recycled so no `init` functions get called. the better approach is to use `didSet` on your `collectionElement` variable and do whatever view updating based on the new value there after ensuring it isn't `nil`. Then when you set the property of the cell in `tableView(tableView: , cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` the cell will actually update itself.

```
var collectionElement  : PFObject = PFObject(className:"CollectionElement") {
    didSet {
        // Update the cell's view elements here, rather than an init function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView reuses cells, and it's responsible for creating them.
You are NOT creating the cell: as the method explains by its name, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier just gets an already created (and probably used) cell from the table view.

Imagine that, given your cell size and device screen, the tableView can show 10 rows at a time. It will create a few more, lets say 12, and then will call cellForRowAtIndexPath on the UITableViewDataSource every time it needs to fill a cell with new information to make it visible.

When you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, you get one of those already created cells, and you're responsible for updating the necessary elements on it to reflect the underlying data. You can thus not assume that any part of it will be "empty" or uninitialized.

Comment: How can I pass data in that case?

Comment: Can you update your question? I fail to see what you're trying to do. It seems to me that what you're trying to do in the init method of the cell is to update something in your view controller, and not the other way round as your question suggests.